# Do apps in focus get more network bandwidth on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth

When downloading large files in the background with a Download Manager, I noticed that whenever I switch to focus the download tab, the speed would increase often by ~1 MBps.

My internet speed is stable at ~140 mbps. I do not think any software is taking up my bandwidth and I was wondering if there is a reason for this speed difference.

Is there a network bandwidth allocation difference between tabs in focus and tabs in the background?

Comment: The speed changes you see are likely due to a feature within the unspecified download manager.  Is there any reason you are using a download manager when every browser already has one?

Comment: @Ramhound I use it to speed up large downloads (multiple connections)

Comment: You don't specify which download manager you are using, but it could in theory, work differently if it has focus.  I don't entirely agree with the accepted answer so I won't be returning to this question.  iTunes (which has not seen a significant update in years) and a download manager are two entirely different beasts.

Comment: I clarified my answer that one method was iTunes and the other method was a Web / Download manager.

Comment: The program with the focus is scheduled to run more often on the CPU. Unless your CPU is maxed out it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is any bandwidth difference related to "in focus" or behind an in focus window.

If I download an IOS upgrade (4GB), the rate of download does not change (beyond the normal vagaries of bandwidth changes) whether iTunes is in front or behind.

If I monitor a download with DU Meter (not using iTunes, but Web or a download manager), the graph is constant (within the vagaries of bandwidth changes) whether the downloading app is in front or behind.

I do not see a reason for focus to change the rate of download.

The change you are seeing (< 1%) is within the range of instantaneous bandwidth changes based on conditions.